# How to derive IV and key to crypto.createCipheriv for decryption?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

I have seen other questions which ask about creating the initialization vector (IV) for [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963624/what-are-the-correct-settings-for-crypto-pbkdf2-to-derive-iv-and-key-to-crypto-c) and it seems using a random value is one option.  However, I need to generate the IV for decryption, so I have to use the same one that the data was encrypted with based on some salt.

The node.js crypto function [createDecipher](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options) says:

> The implementation of crypto.createDecipher() derives keys using the
>   OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5,
>   one iteration, and no salt.

For backwards compatibility with assets encrypted by other software, I need a different number of iterations, and a salt that I specify.

Continuing to read the documentation, it further says:

> In line with OpenSSL's recommendation to use PBKDF2 instead of
>   EVP_BytesToKey it is recommended that developers derive a key and IV
>   on their own using crypto.pbkdf2() and to use crypto.createDecipheriv()
>   to create the Decipher object.

Ok, that sounds good. The data I need to decrypt was encrypted using EVP_BytesToKey to get the key and IV, so I need to be compatible with that, though.

Anyway, the [crypto.pbkdf2 function](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) appears to take all the parameters I need it to, but the problem is, it does not appear to create an initialization vector.

The corresponding C code which did the decryption which this needs to be compatible with looks like this:

```
// parameters to function:
// unsigned char *decrypt_salt
// int nrounds
// unsigned char *decrypt_key_data  <- the password
//  int decrypt_key_data_len <- password length

// the following is not initialized before the call to EVP_BytesToKey
unsigned char decrypt_key[32], decrypt_iv[32];

EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_md5(), decrypt_salt, decrypt_key_data,
                   decrypt_key_data_len, nrounds, decrypt_key, decrypt_iv);
```

My attempt to use `crypto.pbkdf2` to replicate this behavior:

```
crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, nrounds, 32, "md5", (err, derivedKey) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(derivedKey.toString("hex"))
})
```

The `derivedKey` also does not match the key produced by the C code above.  I'm not sure if that's even expected!  I also tried key lengths of 48 and 64 but those didn't generate anything similar to the expected key and IV either.

Given the correct password, salt, and hashing rounds, how do I generate the same key and IV to decrypt with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To start, the reason you are not getting your desired result is because the C code you have **does** use `EVP_BytesToKey`, whereas your NodeJS code uses PBKDF2.  I think you may have misunderstood the recommendation of OpenSSL.  They recommend PBKDF2, not as a better way to produce the same result, but as a better way to solve the problem.  PBKDF2 is simply a better key derivation function, but it will not produce the same result as `EVP_BytesToKey`.

Further, the way you are handling your IV generation in the first place is quite poor.  Using a KDF to generate your key is excellent, well done.  Using a KDF to generate an IV is, frankly, quite a poor idea.  Your initial readings, where you found that generating an IV randomly is a good idea, are correct.  **All IVs/nonces should be generated randomly.  Always.**  The important thing to keep in mind here is that an IV is not a secret.  You can pass it publicly.

Most implementations will randomly generate an IV and then prefix it to the ciphertext.  Then, when it comes to decrypting, you can simply remove the first 128-bits (AES) worth of bytes and use that as the IV.  This covers all your bases and means you don't have to derive your IV from the same place as the key material (which is yucky).

For further information, see the examples in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).  I have included the NodeJS one below, which is an example of best-practice modern encryption in NodeJS:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const ALGORITHM_NAME = "aes-128-gcm";
const ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE = 12;
const ALGORITHM_TAG_SIZE = 16;
const ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE = 16;
const PBKDF2_NAME = "sha256";
const PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE = 16;
const PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 32767;

function encryptString(plaintext, password) {
    // Generate a 128-bit salt using a CSPRNG.
    let salt = crypto.randomBytes(PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);

    // Derive a key using PBKDF2.
    let key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password, "utf8"), salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE, PBKDF2_NAME);

    // Encrypt and prepend salt.
    let ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt = Buffer.concat([ salt, encrypt(new Buffer(plaintext, "utf8"), key) ]);

    // Return as base64 string.
    return ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt.toString("base64");
}

function decryptString(base64CiphertextAndNonceAndSalt, password) {
    // Decode the base64.
    let ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt = new Buffer(base64CiphertextAndNonceAndSalt, "base64");

    // Create buffers of salt and ciphertextAndNonce.
    let salt = ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt.slice(0, PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);
    let ciphertextAndNonce = ciphertextAndNonceAndSalt.slice(PBKDF2_SALT_SIZE);

    // Derive the key using PBKDF2.
    let key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(new Buffer(password, "utf8"), salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, ALGORITHM_KEY_SIZE, PBKDF2_NAME);

    // Decrypt and return result.
    return decrypt(ciphertextAndNonce, key).toString("utf8");
}

function encrypt(plaintext, key) {
    // Generate a 96-bit nonce using a CSPRNG.
    let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE);

    // Create the cipher instance.
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM_NAME, key, nonce);

    // Encrypt and prepend nonce.
    let ciphertext = Buffer.concat([ cipher.update(plaintext), cipher.final() ]);

    return Buffer.concat([ nonce, ciphertext, cipher.getAuthTag() ]);
}

function decrypt(ciphertextAndNonce, key) {
    // Create buffers of nonce, ciphertext and tag.
    let nonce = ciphertextAndNonce.slice(0, ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE);
    let ciphertext = ciphertextAndNonce.slice(ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE, ciphertextAndNonce.length - ALGORITHM_TAG_SIZE);
    let tag = ciphertextAndNonce.slice(ciphertext.length + ALGORITHM_NONCE_SIZE);

    // Create the cipher instance.
    let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM_NAME, key, nonce);

    // Decrypt and return result.
    cipher.setAuthTag(tag);
    return Buffer.concat([ cipher.update(ciphertext), cipher.final() ]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Luke, just wanted to clarify your statement "All IVs/nonces should be generated randomly. Always." You meant always on the encryption step, or? We can not decrypt something with random generated IV/nonce, am I right? So this is the reason why we should send salt AND IV/nonce with cipher text. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Artiom , yes that is correct.  The IV/nonce used to *encrypt* should always be randomly generated.  The IV/nonce used during *decryption* should, as you correctly note, be the same one used during encryption.